# Apply style to first div with specific class in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a reusable accordion component but what I'm trying to achieve is for the first accordion to have a greater padding set, compared to the others. Can this be achieved via CSS? If not, what's the best way to achieve this via jQuery/JS.

Note: I can't just add a class to the first section, as I've stated, it's a reusable component, so the markup is always the same.

```
<!-- Apply padding to this section only -->
<section class="accordion-wrapper">
 <p>Some content in here</p> 
</section>

<section class="accordion-wrapper">
 <p>Some content in here</p> 
</section>

<section class="accordion-wrapper">
 <p>Some content in here</p> 
</section>

<section class="accordion-wrapper">
 <p>Some content in here</p> 
</section>
```

Comment: You could use the `first-of-type`-pseudo-class: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type

Comment: Could you show us more of your HTML structure because first-of-type might be useful but it can't be used in all general cases to select the first element in a DOM that has that class.

Comment: @AHaworth https://codepen.io/Mazmius/pen/KKyYzzY

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my answer to show this can be done by CSS for this specific instance, but for the question as asked (which asked for the first  case in the whole DOM) you need the JS version so I've left that in my answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: first-of child won't work and I have updated the answer

You can achieve this way by a workaround with pure `CSS`: select every element of the class that is the sibling of the same class ->  invert it, -> select by the class again.

Working Codepen: https://codepen.io/tusharg09/pen/oNoOxrq

```css
:not(.accordion-wrapper ~ .accordion-wrapper).accordion-wrapper {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<section class="accordion-wrapper">
  <p>Some content in here</p>
</section>

<section class="accordion-wrapper">
  <p>Some content in here</p>
</section>

<section class="accordion-wrapper">
  <p>Some content in here</p>
</section>

<section class="accordion-wrapper">
  <p>Some content in here</p>
</section>
```

Comment: `first-of-type` doesn't work with classes but with element types.

Comment: @Tushar Please check any other classes or attributes are adding while particular according section is displaying

Comment: @DhavalMakwana it will always have a parent, at the very least, the browser will add `<body>`

Comment: Is accordion displaying from iFrame?

Comment: I've uploaded a codepen as it may be easier to see. I've tried applying first-of-type but it doesn't work. https://codepen.io/Mazmius/pen/KKyYzzY

Comment: updated my answer, please check and its working in your codepen as well

Comment: here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/tusharg09/pen/oNoOxrq

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that accordion sections are the only children of some parent element it can be done via css. You can use `first-child` pseudo class:

```
.accordion-wrapper:first-child {
   ...
}
```

Comment: `first-child` selects first child but OP asks for _specific class_.

Comment: Actually what he asks for is: `what I'm trying to achieve is for the first accordion to have a greater padding set` and my code solves this problems so I hope my anwer will be helpful

Comment: Unfortunately it can't solve the general problem. We haven't seen enough of the code to know whether that section is the first-child as we haven't been shown the parent(s).

Comment: Yes, you're right - it's not  bulletproof solution but assuming that in most cases accordions are wrapped in common parent element it should work. To be clear I will update my answer.

Comment: Here's the link to the codepen. first-child and first-of-type both don't work...
https://codepen.io/Mazmius/pen/KKyYzzY
@AHaworth

Comment: Given the simple layout of your HTML you will find main section:first-of-type will work, as will first-child. For a version that works with a more complex layout you need JS and I've put that in an answer in case you need it.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work because besideds elements with `accordion-wrapper` class there are other siblings. If you wrap all `.accordion-wrapper` (without other sibling elements) elements with some `div` it will work. As I mentioned my solution will work "Assuming that accordion sections are the only children of some parent elemen"

Answer (score 0):

While in the simple cases you may be able to use CSS only, for a general solution which works whatever the HTML structure is, you need to use a bit of JS.

This snippet finds the very first occurence of the element with that class in the whole document. It then adds another class to it which sets the padding.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .accordion-wrapper.extra {
      padding: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Apply padding to this section only -->
  <section class="accordion-wrapper">
    <p>Some content in here</p>
  </section>

  <section class="accordion-wrapper">
    <p>Some content in here</p>
  </section>

  <section class="accordion-wrapper">
    <p>Some content in here</p>
  </section>

  <section class="accordion-wrapper">
    <p>Some content in here</p>
  </section>

  <script>
    const first = document.querySelector('.accordion-wrapper');
    first.classList.add('extra');
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

UPDATE: since giving the answer above, I've seen the HTML structure for this specific question and that can be solved by CSS only using:

```
main section:first-of-type
```

as the selector. Just be aware that if the structure changes it may not be right, as indeed the first answer may not be if other such sections are put in above main.

It is perhaps safest to combine the two approaches and in the JS select the first section within main. Depends on the actual use case of course.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are several ways to achieve this. Since you try to build an accordion so you basically know which of your accordion keys will be different shaped, right?

Therefore you can use for example, assigning a second class to your div. Or another way would be, `:nth-child()` like every second or third key will be shaped in another way. You can find the example code snippet outside of the Code itself.

```css
.accordion-wrapper {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.accordion-key {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 10px;
}

.accordion-keyBlack {
  background-color: #111;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion-wrapper">
  <div class="accordion-key">A</div>
  <div class="accordion-key accordion-keyBlack">B</div>
  <div class="accordion-key">C</div>
  <div class="accordion-key">D</div>
  <div class="accordion-key">E</div>
</div>
```

or you can use :nth-child() for example to define that every second key is black or whatever. Further read, here: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

```
.accordion-key:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: #111;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 20px;
}
```

Of course you can use JS as well, but therefore we would need more details, like the logic of key-arrangement itself.

Answer (score -1):

Select ***first div with specific class*** is not possible with CSS. The closest result is:

```css
section {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: red;
}
.accordion-wrapper:first-child,
:not(.accordion-wrapper) + .accordion-wrapper {
  padding: 10px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<section class="something-random"></section>
<!-- first div with class is here -->
<section class="accordion-wrapper"></section>
<section class="accordion-wrapper"></section>
<section class="accordion-wrapper"></section>
<section class="accordion-wrapper"></section>
<section class="accordion-wrapper"></section>
```

It selects first child `.accordion-wrapper:first-child` or an element that is not preceded by an element with the same class `:not(.accordion-wrapper) + .accordion-wrapper`.

**Problem of this approach** is this case:

```css
section {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: red;
}
.accordion-wrapper:first-child,
:not(.accordion-wrapper) + .accordion-wrapper {
  padding: 10px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<section class="something-random"></section>
<!-- first div with class is here -->
<section class="accordion-wrapper"></section>
<section class="accordion-wrapper"></section>
<section class="accordion-wrapper"></section>
<section class="accordion-wrapper"></section>
<section class="accordion-wrapper"></section>
<section class="something-random"></section>
<!-- but this is not first with class -->
<section class="accordion-wrapper"></section>
<section class="accordion-wrapper"></section>
<section class="accordion-wrapper"></section>
```